# Request Quote Button in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add request quote button in product view page that submits all the information in the admin grid instead of view shopping cart.

Actually, I have created two buttons, one is add to cart & other is request for quote.

If the user selected product options like size (which is defined from backend custom option, input type = dropdown). In this case, User can only show add to cart button & request for quote button is hidden.

If the user selected product options like size (which is not manually defined from backend - for example, input type = field). In this user can enter the size from the front end. In this case, a user can only show the request for quote button.

I have done the button cases. But How do I send the selected data in the custom admin grid from the product detail if a user clicks on request for quote button?

or

Just want a page similar to the shopping cart if the user selects a request for a quote but he is not able to proceed to checkout.